# Picasso и SVG изображения

Tags: android, picasso

В библиотеке Picasso есть метод into(ImageView). Но часть подгружаемых моим приложением картинок имеют формат SVG, который ImageView не поддерживает.
Внедрил в зависимость соответствующий jar по работе с SVG; вывод картинки теперь без использования Picasso. Но все же интересно, есть ли способ как то "подружить" данную библиотеку с SVG? Подобных примеров не нашел, но учитываю ростущую популярность данного формата, не вижу пользы от данной библиотеки для андроид разработки (хотя частенько вижу данную опцию в вакансиях). Просветите кто знает.

Comment: Можно другую, более новую либу для картинок попробовать. Вот тут есть ссылка на пример оной для svg: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/2099

Comment: пикассо отлично подходит для простой работы с обычными изображениями. в дополнение к комментарию выше, Glide еще умеет и с гифками работать

Comment: спасибо, покопаюсь в Glide

Comment: опробовал пример по ссылке выше. Грузит SVG, хотя и не все 100%. Проблема в том, что PNG не загружает. Получается надо по любому формат проверять до вызова

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Picasso текущей версии не дружит с SVG-файлами. На гитхабе есть [дисскусия](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/1109), где задают вопрос разработчику по этому поводу, но обещанный релиз 3.0 пока еще не вышел. Ждемс...

Как вариант, попробуйте использовать **Glide**, похожую библиотеку, она умеет работать с svg. Вот тут более [детально](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28215625/androidload-svg-file-from-web-and-show-it-on-image-view)